# MVC annotation-driven

Tags: java, spring

I came up with the following issue. I couldn't open neither of my web-pages after I had added a resource mapping to the spring-config:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

But, after I added

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

it got work fine. Why? Couldn't someone explain what the tag does?

Comment: This question has already been answered numerous times, search stack overflow and you'll find several posts about what it does.  Also the Spring documentation explains it as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does <mvc:annotation-driven /> do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162459/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do)

Comment: @ChristopherShannnon In the topic you provided said that the annotation allowed to dispatch requests. But, the requests could be dispatched without it. I needed to add this annotation only when I configure resources.