# What is the need and use of <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is the need of `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in Spring MVC . When should we use it. When exactly is it needed. Why should we use it. I gone through few links in stackoverflow, but could not get clear picture or understanding. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**What is the need of `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in `Spring MVC`?**

Using this `handler` spring dispatcher will forward all requests to the default `Servlet`. To enable the feature either you can use annotations or xml based configuration as  below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Or in XML:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

**What it will do?**

The `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` will attempt to `auto-detect` the `default Servlet` for the `container` at startup time, using a list of known names for most of the major Servlet containers (including Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish, JBoss, Resin, WebLogic, and WebSphere). If the default Servlet has been custom configured with a different name, or if a different Servlet container is being used where the default Servlet name is unknown, then the default Servlet’s name must be explicitly provided as in the following example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable("myCustomDefaultServlet");
    }
}
```

Or in XML:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="myCustomDefaultServlet"/>
```

**When should we use it? When exactly is it needed? Why should we use it?**

When you want spring dispatcher to serve `static resources` under the `web root` using default servlet.

If we are using `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`, then we can replace :

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

with :

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

More you can explore [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler).

Answer (score 6):

Because we usually config the DispatcherServlet with the mapping "/*",but all requests such as *.js/*.css will also be mapped to DispatcherServlet,so we need a HttpRequestHandler to dispatch these static resources requests to DefaultServlet.

Answer (score 2):

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

This tag usually use for getting resourses like *.js, *.css, *.jpg and etc.

Tag mvc:default-servlet-handler use DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler which has **low property** (Integer.MAX_VALUE) than handlers in **mvc:annotation-driven:**

- DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
- AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
- AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolve
- [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162459/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do)

**For example**

Your request like ( http://localhost:8080/jquery.js ) first will be search Controller mapping @RequsetMapping("jquery.js"), and when request don't find any Controller mapping try to get resourse in your folder **web** or **webapp**.

If you have **webapp/jquery.js**, you get this file.