# Spring MVC: cannot find other html files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

Why the link http://localhost:8080/demo00/user/ didn't work, saying 404, how to fix it?
My website project structure:
[website structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8MXr.png)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo00</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo00 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>demo00</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Autowired -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/view/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo576" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demo.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">demo576</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

     <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

user.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello User!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

UserController.java:

```
package com.demo.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.demo.model.User;
import com.demo.service.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("user");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (userServices.saveOrUpdate(user)) {
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Your record have been saved successfully");
        }

        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> list(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        List<User> list = userServices.list();

        if (list != null) {
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Data found");
            map.put("data", list);
        } else {
            map.put("status", "404");
            map.put("message", "Data not found");

        }

        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> delete(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (userServices.delete(user)) {
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Your record have been deleted successfully");
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

I followed some tutorials step by step, but cannot figure out what's wrong here.
I am using Eclipse Neon + Tomcat 8 + Java 1.8 in Windows 10.
Please help, thanks in advance.

If there are improper codes or structures, please also point out.

**EDIT:**
I changed some xml and java files according to following suggestions, and uploaded the demo project to https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0rahvz4u29jzey/demo00-160828-url-does-no-work.zip?dl=0, please have a check if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Link http://localhost:8080/demo00/ works and shows the content of index.jsp

Comment: Do you mind to change `@RequestMapping("user")` to `@RequestMapping("/user")` and test again?

Comment: I changed `@RequestMapping("user")` to `@RequestMapping("/user")` in UserController.java, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `applicationContext.xml` is not scanned at time of `application bootup` which eventually throws `404` for all the resources defined in `applicationContext.xml`. To make context load add file as part of `contextConfigLocation` in `web.xml`, as follows:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Next, remove `mvc:resources` from `applicationContext.xml` and add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` and as you are using `Spring 4` do update the schema location to `Spring 4` rather than `Spring 3`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Autowired -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo576" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demo.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">demo576</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

     <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If you want to know more about `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`, checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346267/what-is-the-need-and-use-of-mvcdefault-servlet-handler).

Besides above changes, provide unique `@RequestMapping` url in `UserController.java` otherwise it will throw `Circular view path` exception, I modified `@RequestMapping` at class level to `/users` to avoid the same, as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView get() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("user");
    return view;
 }
}
```

Now, opening the `http://localhost:8080/demo00/users` should display `user.html` page as below:

[image]

Comment: Tested, but didn't work. I uploaded this demo on 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0rahvz4u29jzey/demo00-160828-url-does-no-work.zip?dl=0 
if possible, please have a check. Thanks.

Comment: Wow...you did it! Thank you so much :) I still have a question, you modified `@RequestMapping` at class level to `/users` to avoid the same. The same as what? I tried `/user` and `http://localhost:8080/demo00/user` works too, no `Circular view path` exception happened.

Comment: @J.W: By same I mean `Circular view path exception`. As `@RequestMapping("/user") public class UserController` and `ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("user"); return view;` calls the same url `/user`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you some changes in your project structure and .xml files.

1) you should keep **view** folder in **WEB-INF** folder.

2) you can remove these mappings :-

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/view/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

3) **use this**

property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"

**instead of this**

property name="prefix" value="/view/"

Comment: Thanks. And how about css, js, img, and fonts folders, where should they go?

Comment: no need to change path of these folder. These folders always should be outside of WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

you can put  css, js, img, and fonts folders at one location in webapps/resources and make this below entry in app context file  :

```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
```

And you can remove below lines in you app context file  :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/view/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Secondly put you view folded in WEB-INF and change entry in your app context file :

```
       <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And lastly you can write your controller like this for default get method :
No need to use value attribute as you are not giving any other url here .

```
  @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("user");
        return view;
    }
```

then you can hit :

```
  http://localhost:8080/demo00/user
```

Comment: Tried, the link still didn't work. But your suggestions are making the code structure more proper and readable. Thanks.