# No mapping found for resource files in DispatcherServlet

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've got the following problem on every single page I am trying to access

> WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping
>   found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/cart/%3Cc:url%20value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'%20/%3E] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc-dispatcher

There are warnings, but those resources are visible (both css and scripts are working, still gives errors), and I have nothing underlined in jsp files.

`<link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"/>`

`<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>`

I have above paths to css and js in every jsp file.

**Project-Structure**

[image]

**And my filter mapping:**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you added `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` - as explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346267/what-is-the-need-and-use-of-mvcdefault-servlet-handler?

Comment: Yes. So intellij console is clear now and everything is working, but in a browser console I still have 
`GET http://localhost:8080/products/%3Cc:url%20value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'%20/%3E `

Is it normal? @Arpit

Comment: Your tags aren't working as you can clearly see from the URL that is being called. So I highly doubt your JSP are actualy being server or parsed correctly.

Comment: Do you have `JSTL` in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, I do have JSTL in my classpath.

Comment: As @M.Deinum mentioned, check if `JSP` is compiled properly or not, because I can see `JSTL` tags are not processed -  `http://localhost:8080/products/%3Cc:url%20value='/resources/‌​css/bootstrap.css'%2‌​0/%3E`

Comment: Post some actuall configuration... Most of the things in your post aren't even relevant...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used DispatcherServlet in your mapping. Just try this.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
```