# Simplify ResourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler(..)?

Tags: spring-mvc

Every time I want to use ResourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler(..) to tell Spring a certain directory is resource, I need to specify a path for the handler and a path for resource location, for instance.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/javascript/**").addResourceLocations("/javascript/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**").addResourceLocations("/html/");
```

This gets very repetitive when I have more than one resource directory. Is it possible to tell Spring MVC, "/html" or "/javascript" are resource directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from this other StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349904/1772825

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every directory is a directory in spring.
To exclusively specify resource folder you have to have this configuration.
Otherwise for all resource requests spring will start finding out controller mapping.