# Spring MVC Controller issue : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Yes. I know this is familiar issue. I have looked into other solutions and they didn't help me. I am trying to build Spring MVC Application with Spring 4, Hibernate 5, My Sql and Angular JS 1.x

**Problem**: As shown in image, When I run the application, it resolved to index.jsp file as expected, then I entered '`http://localhost:8080/TimeLee/user/test`' to get web page 'adduser.html' . Boom, it throws following error '**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TimeLee/WEB-INF/views/adduser.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher**'. I checked controller mappings and everything looks good.

[image: Folder Structure and Error message from log]

[image: Browser Output]

UserController:

```
package com.timelee.users.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.timelee.users.model.User;
import com.timelee.users.services.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/adduser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/getuser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam("userId") String userId)
    {
        return userService.getUser(userId);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public  ModelAndView test()
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("adduser");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test2",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public  String test2()
    {
        return "adduser";
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
      <context:component-scan  base-package="com.timelee.*" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


     <!--  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  -->

     <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.timelee.timesheet.model</value>
                <value>com.timelee.users.model</value>
                <value>com.timelee.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>       
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Just add <mvc:annotation-driven/> and clean your project from Eclipse-->Menubar--->Projrct--->Clean and restart the project

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work. I still see the error

Comment: you're working with the views in the bounds of `@RestController` class, that's wrong, use the `@Controller` instead. The `@RestController` annotation is the shortcut for `@ResponseBody` to be specified at the each controller's method. For the now, there're objects to be returned will be converted to JSON and passed straight into the server response instead of view templates lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the info Will. Would it be possible to use one controller for both (REST calls and User Requests)?

Comment: @John, yes. You have to specify `@ResponseBody` annotation at the each REST method before the return value declaration inside `@Controller` annotated сlass.

Comment: In that case, I can not use single method for both REST calls and web requests. Is that so? If that's the case I need to have separate method for Web request, which creates redundancy. Any suggestions?

Comment: the method separation is required for the case you're describe. Actually, there's no redundancy. Both methods are have to refer the same service logic so there's no even boilerplate. Mixing the both REST and web-request approaches to the single method isn't the good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` in `spring-mvc-config.xml`file. Clean the project and rebuild it. This may solve your issue.

Comment: Can you explain why is this required. Here it says is is used to serve static resource https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349904/10195722 but in my case even JSP page was not being rendered. Is JSP also considered as a static resource like css, jpg, etc??

Answer (score 1):

I guess try to add in `spring-mvc-config.xml`. Hope this will work for you. Other things looks good.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Next try is add those code in the top of `web.xml` file. it seems different in your case.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

 </web-app>
```

If it does not work for you then follow my link and see the difference [web.xml](https://github.com/ramesh-kc/restAPI/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) as well as [application-context.xml](https://github.com/ramesh-kc/restAPI/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml) and [dispatcher-servlet.xml](https://github.com/ramesh-kc/restAPI/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml)

Comment: Nope. It did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to know that is adduser is a jap or HTML file? If yes than use simple return for it.

Second is you create `adduser` post method in your controller, right? Add `adduser` get method in controller.
Like

```
@requestmapping(value="adduser",requestmethod.GET)
public String adduser(){
     Return // return page name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, is adduser is a `jap` or `HTML` file? If HTML then use simple return for it.

Second, is your create `adduser` `POST` method in your controller? Add `adduser` `GET` method in controller.

Like:

```
@requestmapping(value="adduser",requestmethod.GET)
public String adduser(){
     Return // return page name
}
```

Here, the 404 error only shows that there is no `adduser.html` or `adduser.jsp` available in your `webinf` folder or where you put all of your `jap/HTML` files.