# webjars bloc all my pages (spring mvc and maven project)

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, webjars

i'm using webjars in spring mvc with the same configuration as webjars docs but when i add this line i got 404 error for all the pages :

> mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"

what's the problem please ??

part from pom.xml:

```
<!-- webJars -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>materializecss</artifactId>
    <version>0.97.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

part from dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
```

part from web.xml

```
<web-app>

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and the jsp:

```
<head>
<title>log in</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="webjars/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="webjars/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tag  mvc:annotation-driven was messing from the configuration file for more informations about it see :

[stackoverflow :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162459/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do)
[What does <mvc:annotation-driven /> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162459/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do)

[spring docs :](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html